# Better caption for align/gather

Tags: align, captions, gather

I want to add small captions under the `align` and `gather` math groups that I make in my notes. I just added something like `\begin{center}`, then some `\small` text for a centered small text look. Here is the code:

```
Denoted by $\neg Q \implies \neq P$, logically equivalent to $P \implies Q$.
\begin{align*}
    \neg Q \implies \neq P &\equiv \neq(\neq Q) \lor (\neq P) \equiv Q \lor (\neq P) \\
    &\equiv \neq P \lor Q \\
    &\equiv P \implies Q \\
\end{align*}
\begin{center}
\small{In English: If statement reads ``if $P$, then $Q$'', then contrapositive reads ``if not $Q$, then not $P$''}
\end{center}
Contrapositive and statement essentially have the same meaning.
```

But it has a huge space, which I find quite irritating - it looks like so:

[image]

I also tried replacing the `\begin{center}` content with `\captionof*{align}{This is a caption}` from the caption package, but no luck - it has the same ugly space:

[image]

Is there any sort of workaround for this or a way to add in the caption without having it eat up too many extra lines? Thanks!

Comment: Try  (within the `align*` environment):  `\\ \intertext{\centering This is a caption}`, or even with `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`.

Comment: `center` environment adds vertical space.  `\centering` macro preferred in such situations, but needs to be group-limited to end it.

Comment: note that `\small` does not take an argument so `\small In English...` not `\small{In Enhlish...`   I would also suggest `\intertext`

Comment: Hi, I tried intertext - however, it ended up delaying the space. So the space between align and caption are fine, but now there is a massive space between caption and the text below (Contrapositive and statement...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem was the extra `\\` before the end of the `align*` environment.  Unlike `tabular`, align environments don't forget it.

However, I also use `\centering` in lieu of the `center` environment, as the latter also adds vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Denoted by $\neg Q \implies \neq P$, logically equivalent to $P \implies Q$.
\begin{align*}
    \neg Q \implies \neq P &\equiv \neq(\neq Q) \lor (\neq P) \equiv Q \lor (\neq P) \\
    &\equiv \neq P \lor Q \\
    &\equiv P \implies Q 
\end{align*}
{\centering
\small In English: If statement reads ``if $P$, then $Q$'', then 
  contrapositive reads ``if not $Q$, then not $P$''\par
}
Contrapositive and statement essentially have the same meaning.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd define my own environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newenvironment{captionedalign*}
 {%
  \mathtoolsset{below-shortintertext-sep=-\belowdisplayskip}
  \let\caption\captionedaligncaption
  \csname align*\endcsname
 }
 {\endalign}
\newcommand{\captionedaligncaption}[1]{%
  \shortintertext{\centering\footnotesize #1}%
}

\begin{document}

Denoted by $\neg Q \Longrightarrow \neg P$, logically equivalent to $P \Longrightarrow Q$.
\begin{captionedalign*}
  \neg Q \Longrightarrow \neg P &\equiv \neg(\neg Q) \lor (\neg P) \equiv Q \lor (\neg P) \\
  &\equiv \neg P \lor Q \\
  &\equiv P \Longrightarrow Q \\
  \caption{In English: If statement reads ``if $P$, then $Q$'', then contrapositive \\
    reads ``if not $Q$, then not $P$''}
\end{captionedalign*}
Contrapositive and statement essentially have the same meaning.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes.**
I replaced all `\neq` commands with `\neg`.
Also `\implies` is not the right command, because it adds too wide horizontal space. Personally, I'd use `\to` or `\Rightarrow`.